# Retrieve/reproduce design matrix from smooth.spline in R

Tags: r, spline

I would like to know how to retrieve or reproduce the design matrix used under the hood by `smooth.spline`.  It does not appear that `smooth.spline` has a way to return this matrix. As such, I am trying to reproduce the matrix by using the `bs` function.

When I run `smooth.spline` and specify the knots via the `all.knots` argument, the number of parameters from the fit is off by one compared to the bspline matrix I get by passing the same knots to the `bs` function. Can someone help me understand how to reproduce the training matrix that's being used under the hood by `smooth.spline` given a known set of knots? Thanks!

Here is code that reproduces the behavior:

```
n = 200
y = rnorm(n=n)
x = runif(n=n)
knots = c(0,seq(0.001,0.999,.01),1)
mod = smooth.spline(x,y,all.knots=knots,keep.stuff=TRUE)

X = bs(x,knots=knots)

dim(X)[2] #105 
length(mod$fit$coef) #104
```

Comment: The [help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/smooth.spline.html) page suggests that `keep.stuff=TRUE` might be a way to go

Comment: Yes this is a good place to start.  When I used `keep.stuff=TRUE`, the `mod$data` only contains the original `x` not the design, the `mod$auxM` attribute contains the `XWy` and `XWX` components, but not the `X` component, nor can it be solved for from those. None of the others seem to have it.

Comment: well the help page *helpfully* says that "Should allow to reconstruct the X matrix and more." ....more helpful would be to show how to do it.  Hopefully someone knows how to do it

Comment: Do any of the components of `mod$fit` provide sufficient info?

Comment: If what you want really can't be reconstructed from those components you might be out of luck. Might be worth asking on `r-devel@r-project.org` and/or pinging Martin Mächler ... I don't think `chol()` will do it, but (assuming for now weights are trivial) is there a matrix factorization that will retrieve `X` from `XWX` ... ? Or maybe reconstruct `XW` from `XWy` given a known `y` ... ??

Comment: hm. I have stats 4.2.2 and so far as I can see `keep.stuff` isn't changing the outputs at all.

Comment: Thank you, @BenBolker, I am also trying to solve for X similarly at the moment, however I'm not optimistic because the XWX term is a vector of length 416 which is not a square...

Comment: given how ugly all of this is (e.g. see [here](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/acf386967eb8607fb7967eafec64720e84ad1b65/src/library/stats/src/stxwx.f#L4)) you might actually be better off using a smoothing spline from the `mgcv` package, which will probably make it easier to retrieve the bits you need ...

Comment: Have moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't explain how to use the internal data of the output of `smooth.spline` to get the smoother matrix but we can get that matrix by pumping an identity matrix through `smooth.spline` (which is also a general method of finding the matrix of a linear operator).  Also see [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/dst/18/hw/02/smoother.matrix.R](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/dst/18/hw/02/smoother.matrix.R)

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 200
y <- rnorm(n)
x <- runif(n)
mod <- smooth.spline(x, y, keep.stuff = TRUE)

S <- apply(diag(n), 2, function(y) fitted(smooth.spline(x, y, df = mod$df)))

max(abs(S %*% y - fitted(mod)))
## [1] 2.183287e-08
```

If you only need the diagonal of the smoother matrix then `hatvalues(mod)` will give that.

```
max(abs(diag(S) - hatvalues(mod)))
## [1] 1.676781e-08
```

This computes a matrix X which satisfies Xb = Sy.

```
b <- mod$fit$coef
X <- tcrossprod(fitted(mod), b/c(crossprod(b)))

max(abs(X %*% b - S %*% y))
## [1] 4.959864e-09
```

The equation is satisfied because if X = (Sy)b'/(b'b) then Xb = ((Sy)b'/(b'b))b = (Sy)(b'b)/(b'b) = Sy .

Note that such an X is not unique since if we add vectors orthogonal to b to rows of X then the equation is still satisfied.

Although the X we showed does satisfy the equation asked for I am not sure if it really is what you want.  Note that looking at the [source](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/tests/smooth.spline.R) we can convert mod$auxM to a list of matrices like this:

```
aux2Mat <- function(auxM) {
    stopifnot(is.list(auxM),
              identical(vapply(auxM, class, ""),
                        setNames(rep("numeric", 4), c("XWy", "XWX", "Sigma", "R"))))
    ## requireNamespace("Matrix")# want sparse matrices
    nk <- length(XWy <- auxM[["XWy"]])
    list(XWy = XWy,
         XWX =  Matrix::bandSparse(nk, k= 0:3, diagonals= matrix(auxM[[ "XWX" ]], nk,4), symmetric=TRUE),
         Sigma= Matrix::bandSparse(nk, k= 0:3, diagonals= matrix(auxM[["Sigma"]], nk,4), symmetric=TRUE))
}
lM <- aux2Mat(mod$auxM)
A <- lM$XWX + mod$lambda * lM$Sigma
R <- Matrix::chol(A)
```

The following two lines give the same result:

```
bb <- solve(A, lM$XWy)
b <- mod$fit$coef

max(abs(b - bb))
## [1] 1.125863e-10
```

Also these two are the same

```
crossprod(b, as.matrix(lM$XWX)) %*% b
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.01597881
crossprod(X %*% b)
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.01597881
```

and these two are the same

```
y %*% X %*% b
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.02039534
lM$XWy %*% b
##            [,1]
## [1,] 0.02039534
```

### Update

Corrections.

Comment: Thank you.  I apologize if there was ambiguity in my question, but this answer provides the smoother/hat matrix S, whereas I am trying to recover the X matrix such that Xb = Sy where b are the coefficients.  Now that we have the smoother matrix S it may be easier to recover X, trying to solve that now.

Comment: This works, thank you @G. Grothendiek!  Now I'm trying to understand why... Can you add this to your solution so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: This may be a better test and has negligible error, `max(abs(X%*%mod$fit$coef - predict(mod)$y))`

Comment: Have moved comment to answer.

Comment: Thank you for these additional updates @G. Grothendieck.  It seems you have doubts that the X you derived is what I want.  Is your only concern that it's not unique up to a shift by vector orthogonal to b?  Or is there another concern?  None of the three updates you added at the bottom retrieve X directly so I'm still using `X <- tcrossprod(fitted(mod), b/c(crossprod(b)))`.  This appears to be sufficient for me because it enables me to generate an X* for a new set of data but preprocessed in the same way as X.

Comment: The point of the updates it that b is not only the solution to Xb = Sy but is also the solution to Ab = lM$XWy so maybe it is really A you want and not X?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, @G. Grothendieck.  The update you provided is very helpful as there was no information previously on how to make use of the data stored in the `auxM` attribute.  For my current purposes, the `X` matrix is what I need, since i need to reproduce predictions/fitted values from the model without using the predict function.  As such, `X%*%b` appears to be  `predict(mod)$y`, a 200 length vector.  Whereas, `A` is 101x101 in our example, and I'm not sure how to use that to get predictions/fitted values.

Comment: `X %*% b`, `fitted(mod)` and `predict(mod, x)$y` are all equal.